# How to determine the identity provider (IdP)?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

How do I determine the identity provider (IdP) of a web application? I have been assigned to manage an LMS web application (I have basic admin privileges) that I am unfamiliar with and they would like to integrate SSO using SAML. I figure this is a noob question but I cannot find guidance on the topic anywhere.

I tried checking other threats on stackoverflow but I don't think any were this basic. I also tried going through the authorization settings of the LMS site but did not see anything helpful. Our site does have a sign in with google option (not sure if that shed's any light)

{No code to show}

Comment: You need to know the IdP before anything, it's the source of all user info. It's not something that gets discovered randomly. There's also metadata exchange process where IdP agrees to feed you data, and you get IdP's keys to assert the data is coming from known source. It's not a noob question but it's not as trivial as you might think. If I'm not mistaken, sign in with google uses OpenID Connect, which is a similar protocol but it uses JSON, opposed to SAML which uses XML. Do you have ANY info on where or who your IdP should be?

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I don't have any of that info - our senior dev, is also the CTO who is kinda backed up at the moment. I viewed the page source for the login page and saw an oauth/google/authenticate route.

Comment: ^^^^ @N.B. Thank you

Comment: Use Fiddler and see what the app is doing now. It's probably going to /authorize and /token endpoints (i.e. OpenID Connect). If you want to add SAML, you need to check that the IDP supports this

Comment: Thank you @nzpcmad. I will look into Fiddler to see if I can uncover any useful info.

Comment: If someone else (like me) doesn't know what LMS means: Learning Management System

Answer (score 0):

If the LMS supports SAML out of the box, consult LMS docs on how to configure SAML on LMS side. The LMS will likely be a service provider. The identity provider will be an entity external to LMS. You will need to talk to admins of the identity provider so they can supply you with information about the identity provider. This information is known as SAML metadata; it is often provided in XML format. You will need to enter this information in config screens on LMS side. Sometimes the identity provider and/or the service provider will have instructions that show specific configuration steps for getting the other party to work with them; this might be your best bet for "out of the box" setup.

If the LMS doesn't support SAML, then all bets are off.

Comment: Thank you @identigral. Yes, the docs for the SP mentioned the need for an XML metadata. I reached out to the senior dev/admin for further guidance. I appreciate the thorough response.

Comment: @idenitgral our platform uses LDAP. Can SAML SSO be used with an LDAP platform? (Thanks again)

Comment: @coolnuhman It depends on the implementation. SAML as a protocol doesn't prescribe where the user identities reside or how they're found. It's pretty typical to have a SAML service provider rely on LDAP to find the user. As a very crude sequence of steps, SAML tells the service provider that user "foo" has been authenticated by the identity provider and the service provider could then retrieve the user record and/or more details about user "foo" via LDAP.